# What's a painless way to "require" modules not in your node_modules/ folder?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have some javascript files that export some common functions in use in my app. I want to be able to import those files simply by writing `var example = require('example')` rather than `var example = require('../local_modules/example')`

How do I accomplish this without adding it to the npm registry? They have to stay private.

Comment: Are you using any kind of build system? Webpack has a way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a path mapping. For example

```
var pathmapping = {
    example: '../local_modules/example'
    ...other pathes...
}
```

Then access them by

```
require(pathmapping[example])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the full path to `../local_modules` to `$NODE_PATH`.

If you're using a Unix-type OS:

```
NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/full/path/to/local_modules
```

If you do that from your shell's startup file, it'll "stick".

However, ideally you should always keep your modules local to the project, so in `./node_modules`. If your local modules are proper packages (if not, you should consider making packages from them, which isn't too difficult), just install them there:

```
npm i ../local_modules/your-module
```

Comment: I like this idea, but unfortunately, npm install had removed all the local packages (that weren't included in my package.json) as well :(. It's so weird how I can't find a workaround this problem anywhere on the internet because this was a change between how npm2 and npm3 worked.

Comment: AFAIK, `npm install` never _removes_ packages. I also can't reproduce that issue (where packages installed in `./node_modules` but not mentioned in `package.json` get removed when running `npm install`).

Comment: `npm install` does remove packages which are not mentioned in `package.json`

Comment: @KrisztiánBalla it didn't in April 2017 :P